# Add an image to the map and make sure aspect ratio is correct

Tags: leaflet

I have tried adding an image to Leaflet using ImageOverlay, see for example the following code:

```
imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];
var ol = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(mymap);
```

Now the image is added, but I would like to use the aspect ratio of the image and I would prefer to actually set the image's center point instead of the bounds. Is this at all possible?

Size of the image is not that critical, lets say I want the width to be set to 60% of the current visible area of the map, I then want the height to be calculated so that the aspect ratio of the image is kept.

Problem is I am not sure I can just translate between latitude/longitude and x/y.

Is it correct to assume that the aspect ratio longitude/latitude is the same as for x/y if the map is quite zoomed in?

Is there an easier way to do this maybe?